# Using a DIV as a popup window

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I am building a page that needs several popups to show extra information of some elements, so I build the popups windows using DIV`s tags and just change the display to block or none and the position is absolute, the popup should be displayed when I click on an image button and it should stick beside that button, now my main problem is that when I show up the div the page automatically scrolls all the way up to the start of the page, that make my popup to be on the wrong position, how can I avoid this behavior?

this is my javascript, I use the baseElent to position the div beside my image button

```
function popup(windowName, baseElement, orientation) {
    var ventana = document.getElementById(windowName);
    var windowOrigStyle = ventana.style.display;
    if (lastOpenedWindow != null) 
        lastOpenedWindow.style.display = "none";

    if (windowOrigStyle == 'none') {
        var base = document.getElementById(baseElement);
        var basePosition = base.getBoundingClientRect()
        if (orientation == 'left') {
            var width = ventana.currentStyle.width.replace(/px/g, "");
            var popupTop = basePosition.top;
            var popupLeft = basePosition.left - width - 2;
            popupTop -= 10;
        }
        else {
            var popupTop = basePosition.top;
            var popupLeft = basePosition.right;
            popupTop -= 10;
            popupLeft += 3;
        }
        ventana.style.left = popupLeft + 'px';
        ventana.style.top = popupTop + 'px';
        ventana.style.display = "block";
        lastOpenedWindow = ventana;
    }
    else
        ventana.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: you can use any third party script for popups, yui or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery Dynamic popup. Just pass the div id to the Method.
Demo: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/popups/dynamic-popup.html#demo-page

Answer (score 0):

instead of an absolute position use a fixed position.

```
div {
position: fixed;
}
```